# evaluatePostFix segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, stack, postfix-notation

I'm very close at completing this program, I'm just having an issue with my evaluatePostfix function. When I run my debugger, it states that it's an issue at the very end when I return opstack.top(), but I don't know how to go about fixing it. If anyone could help me, or if anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it!

```
int evaluatePostfix (string postFix)
{
    /* algorithm: 
     Declare a stack of int to store the operands, and also the result of the subexpression 
     scan the expression from left to right, char by char 
     i) if the char is a digit, push the digit's value into the stack...furthermore, loop to read digits until you reach space or operator, and meanwhile finds out the values of the operand...
     ii) if the char is an operand, pop two elements from the stack
          and apply the operation on the two elements, 
          push the result onto the stack 
     when reaching the end of the expression, the value in the stack is the result */
    stack<int> opstack;

    for(int i = 0; i < postFix.length(); i++){

    //Scanning each character from the left
    //If the character is a delimitter, then move on.
    if(postFix[i] == ';'||postFix[i] == ',')continue;

    //If the character is an operator, pop two elements from stack, perform the operation and push the result back.
    if(isOperator(postFix[i])){

    //Pop two operands.
    int op2 = opstack.top();
    opstack.pop();
    int op1 = opstack.top();
    opstack.pop();

    //Perform operation
    int result = PerformOperation(postFix[i], op1, op2);

    //Push back result of operation on stack.
    opstack.push(result);
    }

    else if(isOperand(postFix[i])){

    //Extract the numeric operand from the string
    //Keep incrementing i as long as you are getting a numeric digit.

    int operand = 0;
    while(i < postFix.length() && isOperand(postFix[i])){

    //For a number with more than one digit, as we are scanning from left to right.       
    //Everytime, we get a digit towards the right, we can multiply current total in operand by 10 and add the new digit.
    operand = (operand * 10) + (postFix[i] - '0');

    i++;
    }

    //Finally, you will come out of while loop with i set to a non-numeric character or end of string
    //decrement i because it will be incremented in increment section of loop once again. 
    //We do not want to skip the non-numeric character by incrementing i twice.

    i--;

    //Push the operand on the stack.
    opstack.push(operand);
    }
    }

    //if expression is in correct format, Stack will finally have one element. This will be the output.
    return opstack.top();
}
```